# Salesforce: Internal Server Error

Tags: salesforce, internal

I have a visualforce page which is rendering correctly. There is a commandbutton "Save" which executes some DML statement and redirects to some other page. This functionality was working fine earlier. Since yesterday, on click of the "Save" button, i am getting this error :

```
An internal server error has occurred 
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. 

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com! 

Error ID: 471693248-7806 (-1751278023)
```

I am not able to find out what is the cause of this error. I even tried commenting out all the code in the method called by Save button. Still, i am getting this error. What can be the cause of this type of error?

Comment: What happened when you contacted salesforce support?

Comment: @Wooble The support link doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be caused by something else in your code not related to the Save button. Start by commenting everything out in your controller/extension and save it that way. Then property by property, and method by method un-comment sections; save each time, and review your page. That will give you a better idea where the error occurred. If that doesn't work, call your [Salesforce support number](https://www.salesforce.com/form/contact/contactme.jsp?d=70130000000EeYa&internal=true).

Comment: As per your suggestion, i searched for the cause of error in other code. The rendered attribute seems to be the problem. <apex:outputPanel id="primaryDealerImage" rendered="{!c.Dealer_Number__c==review.Dealer__c}"> <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Style,'Images/primary_dealer_image2.png')}" width="16" height="18" /> </apex:outputPanel> I am still not sure how to remove this error.

Comment: Try using `{!IF(c.Dealer_Number__c==review.Dealer__c,"true","false"}` instead. If that doesn't work check the value of `{!c.Dealer_Number__c}` and `{!review.Dealer__c}` separately.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already tried commenting out your code to no avail, try changing and re-saving the associated .meta file for your class file.

So if your file ClassName.cls-meta.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>20.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Try changing the API version number and re-saving:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <apiVersion>23.0</apiVersion>

    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Also, check to see that your class is listed as both Active and Valid in Name|Setup|Develop|Apex Classes.

Further, your org may have just received its spring upgrade over the weekend and could actually be seeing a genuine Salesforce bug! Log a case and have them troubleshoot it if so.

Good luck